# Android firebase nested-listeners data change problem

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, listener

I'm working with Firebase realtime database. I have a friend list for each user. I'm adding friend list of user to recyclerview. There is no error I can see friend list. But if I change something about user friend information, there is no change in the adapter. If I add a new user to the friend list, adapter senses the changes. 
I use nested firebase listener. First listener for getting user friend ids, second listener for fetching friend information using ids.

I want if the user friend changes its online status, adapter senses it.

This is my json tree:
[image: json tree]

This is my code for fetching user friend list:

```
        databaseReference.child("users").child(user_id).child("friends").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                //friends.clear();
                //friendInfoList.clear();
            //Toast.makeText(FriendsActivity.this, dataSnapshot.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    String friend_id=ds.getValue(String.class);
                    friends.add(new Friends(friend_id));
                    Toast.makeText(FriendsActivity.this, friend_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    databaseReference.child("users").child(friend_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            //friendInfoList.clear();
                                Users user=dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
                                friendInfoList.add(new FriendInfo(user.getUsername(),user.getCountry(),user.isStatus()));
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

                }

           adapter=new FriendListRecyclerAdapter(FriendsActivity.this,friendInfoList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

To update the data in the adapter call the method `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

From the docs:

> [`notifyDataSetChanged`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged())
>
> Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

Comment: Thank you bro . i have tried this. but second listener dont notify the changes. i displayed toast message inside second listener and i change child value in the server. But tost message never displays

Comment: Where did u add notifydatasetchanged?

Comment: i have added before writing this codes. but not working

Comment: Is friendinfolist empty??

Comment: You are not retrieving `friend_id`, in the first listener remove the for loop and add log `friend_id` and tell me what you get

Comment: Thank you Peter . i added notifydatasetchanged to wrong place,thats the one of the problems. and i chanced List<FriendInfo> to FriendInfo in Users class and changed realtime database json tree. i solved problem

Comment: Okay please also mark the answer as correct by clicking the arrow icon next to the answer since it helped you, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you are not triggering "users/user_id/friends" node when friend information has been changed. Also I think you should use "child event listener".